# Cyrillic characters problem

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, cyrillic, russian

I want to write a math paper that needs to be in Bulgarian (uses the same alphabet as Russian). However when I try to compile with pdflatex I get the following error for every cyrillic character:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char н (U+43D)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Here is how my .tex file looks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Полиноми}
\section{1.1 Теорема за деление с частно и остатък на полиноми}
$ F $ = поле и $ f, g \in F[x], g \neq 0$\\
$ \exists! $ двойка полиноми $ q, r \in F[x]$, такива че\\
$ f = gq + r$ и $ deg r < deg g$
\end{document}
```

I am very new to LaTeX so sorry for the simple question, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, but I get no error (after replacing `article` with `book`). What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: This is the output when I query for my version: 

pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0

Comment: It is a bit outdated. Check in the Debian packages that TeX support for Cyrillic is installed. Can you please add the log file up to the first error?

Comment: Not sure that it answers your question, but anycase you should change Babel option russian to somewhat like bulgarian. I 'm sure that Babel provides support for Bulgarian. Maybe, Russian alfabet covers Bulgarian one, but hyphenations are different.